# How do i change background color of silverlight expander?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, controltemplate, expander

I want to change background color of the Silverlight expander.

It look like as follows.

[image]

**How do I edit following template to set background color to white??**

**What property of Expander will do I set to change background color of the Expander.
and its XAML code is as follows.**

```
  <Style x:Key="MyExpanderStyle" TargetType="controlsToolkit:Expander">
        <Setter Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Down"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,3"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controlsToolkit:Expander">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpanderArrowFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#0098D4" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#0098D4" Offset="0.5"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#0098D4" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpanderArrowHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F8FE" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE0F3FE" Offset="0.3"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF6FA7C5" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ExpanderArrowPressedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDCF0FA" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC5E6F7" Offset="0.2"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5690D0" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="M 1,4.5 L 4.5,1 L 8,4.5"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowHoverFill}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#222"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="# "/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="1.5"/>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowPressedFill}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF003366"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowFill}" Stroke="Transparent" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15"/>
                                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="header" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="M 1,4.5 L 4.5,1 L 8,4.5"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowHoverFill}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#222"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF526C7B"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="1.5"/>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="circle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowPressedFill}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF003366"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="9.5" CenterY="9.5"/>
                                                            </TransformCollection>
                                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource ExpanderArrowFill}" Stroke="DarkGray" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="header" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandDirectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ExpandDown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ExpandUp">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Template">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderTemplate}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="cd0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="*"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cd0" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cd1" Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="rd0" Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="rd1" Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Margin="1" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderTemplate}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ExpandSite" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="3"/>
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3">
                            <!--<Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>-->
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the Expander control has a Background Property which is bounded to its embeded Border control via TemplateBinding here:

```
<Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             ...
```

Try to set the corresponding Background property of the expander control via adding the following line to the Expander Style (replace #000000 with your color):

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000"></Setter>
```

Hope that works,
cheers